# Can't see any session values when using Uploadify in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I'm using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) to upload files in my site and in order to make upload more secure I create 'token' (random number) in server side once the page loaded and put it in Session and in JS variable so that when I start upload files I send the same token back to server.
The problem is when sending it back I traced the code and the session values all lost, looks like its another session.
How is that happening and how can I fix it?
Here's a pseudo code in ASP.NET:

**Server side**

```
var token = getRandomNumber();
Session["myToken"] = token;
Response.write("<script> var tokenInJS = "+token+"</script>");
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/) post in Uploadify's manual about a bug in flash that prevents it from posting a session variable.

Comment: didn't read it, it's actually frustrating..I've been looking for good uploader for three days and finally decided to use this one (even thought I didn't want to use flash in my site).

Comment: This link also looks like it may solve your issue. http://snipplr.com/view/15180/aspnet-working-around-flash-cookie-bug-aka-restoring-the-session--swfupload/

Answer (score 0):

```
var token = getRandomNumber();
//put the token into session.
Session["myToken"] = token;

//use session variable
Response.write("<script> var tokenInJS = "+Session["myToken"]+"</script>");
```

Comment: The problem is not using the variable in JS from the Session or the variable 'token'..I don't think it will make any different, nay way I'll try it

Comment: I need more info about assigning variable to token and using token value lines. If it is like exactly on question, session using is wrong.

Comment: It must be like this. Put variable into session when user logins, pages first load, controls first load etc. and then use it everywhere u need.